# Kendo dropdown date formatting

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

How do I format date data from the dataSource to suit the dataTextField in kendoDropDownList? Templates and kendoGrid don't seem to cause a problem, but doing something like `dataTextField: "#:kendo.format('{0:dd MMM yyyy}',data.jscript_date)#"` or variations of it produce errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The dataTextField must simply be the name of a field on the data item from the datasource. To customise what you actually see in the dropdown, put your template code in template and valueTemplate:

```
template: "#:kendo.format('{0:dd MMM yyyy}',data.jscript_date)#",
valueTemplate: "#:kendo.format('{0:dd MMM yyyy}',data.jscript_date)#"
```

The template is for when the dropdown is expanded and the valueTemplate is for the selected item when the dropdown is closed.